# set return_value of function

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

I have a class:

```
class AccountBusiness:
    def save(self, account) -> Account:
        if not account.account_number_is_valid():
            return False

        return True
```

and a test as:

```
@mock.patch.object(AccountBusiness, 'save')
def test_can_save_valid_account(self, mock_save):

    mock_account = mock.create_autospec(Account)
    mock_account.account_number_is_valid.return_value = False

    account_business = AccountBusiness()
    result = account_business.save(mock_account)
    self.assertEqual(result.return_value, True)
```

but it shows an exception like:

```
AssertionError: <MagicMock name='save()()' id='48830448'> != True
```

I want to set the return value of `account.account_number_is_valid()` to `False` and run the test.

Comment: If you set `account_number_is_valid` to `False`, `save` will also return `False` and assertion will fail. What else would you expect? You must set it to `True` if you want the assertion to be successful.

Comment: @Selcuk it doesn't matter the value that have been set. If I set it to True, it again returns the mentioned exception

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using a patch object on the instance method you are looking to test. However, you are looking to test the logic inside the `save` method. So mocking that out will not test any of the logic inside that method. So, the output you are actually getting here:

```
AssertionError: <MagicMock name='save()()' id='48830448'> != True
```

Should be the first hint that something is not right. Your `save` method is coming back as a `MagicMock`. You don't want this. What you actually want to do is only mock the `Account` class, and go accordingly from there. So, your patching here:

```
@mock.patch.object(AccountBusiness, 'save')
```

should actually only be:

```
@mock.patch('path.to.AccountBusiness.Account', return_value=Mock(), autospec=True)
```

The `path.to.AccountBusiness.Account` is the location of the `Account` class with respect to the `AccountBusiness` class.

So, with that patching, then the `return_value` of calling `Account` will now be your mock object that you can use for your `account_number_is_valid`. So, the code will actually look like this:

```
class MyTest(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.account_business = AccountBusiness()

    @mock.patch('path.to.AccountBusiness.Account', return_value=Mock(), autospec=True)
    def test_can_save_valid_account(self, mock_account):
        mock_account_obj = mock_account.return_value
        mock_account_obj.account_number_is_valid.return_value = False

        self.assertFalse(self.account_business.save(mock_account_obj))
```

Also, pay close attention to the assertion at the end. It was changed to make use of the available `assertFalse`. Also, look over your own logic, as returning `False` for `account_number_is_valid` will actually return `False` in your `save` method.